# Swift WebView not loading url html5 game content

Tags: ios, swift, html

Im new in ios. Currently try to build ios apps with xcode 8.3.2 using latest swift code. I come across of a problem where it totally no idea what's the error or limitation on viewing certain link at the Web View page.

example try to display HTML5 game url : 
http://54.152.88.13/tamagotchi/taba.html
http://demonisblack.com/code/mypuki/game/

but so show this is work
http://www.apple.com
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/final.html

Here by code as follow :

```
@IBOutlet weak var GameWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let theurl = URL(string: "http://demonisblack.com/code/mypuki/game/"){

            let theURLRequest = URLRequest(url: theurl)

            GameWebView?.loadRequest(theURLRequest)

        }
    }
```

This is just for my testing purpose and the game is fully copyright by the owner. I just want to understand what is the criterion if i want to build and html5 game and load into my phone apps later.

Comment: I know iOS has made policy stricter about plain-HTTP websites but AFAIK that's for WKWebView. Have you tried with an HTTPS URL?

Comment: @Downgoat Thanks of the hints. It make me more careful about https and http...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a key in your info.plist file allowing insecure (non HTTPS) communication. You can do it on a site by site basis.

[image]

Here is a link to a web page that describes the process completely

https://documentation.hyprmx.com/display/IS/Quick+Start